# Accept both relative and absolute paths in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I would like to make a bash script that accepts both relative and absolute paths. It would be easy to filter with the first character, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. How, when, where do you want to take input that may be relative or absolute? The reason being, it matters whether you can test for file existence. (e.g. `[ -f "$var" ]`) If you are talking about positional parameters, then you can test existence and then use `readlink -f` or `realpath` as suggested by jam. If however, you are not in a context where the test for existence will be true, then neither will help.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a conversion to absolute path for everything passed in using [readlink](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink)?

e.g. say you're in /home/foo, which contains a folder 'bar':

`readlink -f bar` -> /home/foo/bar

`readlink -f /home/foo/bar` -> /home/foo/bar

Comment: Thank you a lot, I did not knew that usage of readlink (neither realpath) !!! (I upvoted you answer but have not enough reputation for it to become visible)

Answer (score 0):

Using readlink -f or realpath fits perfectly my needs !